# Measure-object Sum not returning Sum of array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array that If I query a column, I get a list of numbers in return.  If I place into Measure-Object, the Sum is not correct?

What is most efficient way to Sum this list of numbers?

```
 $array.'Profit'
```

Returns...

- 0.000
- 0.000
- 0.000
- 2387.500
- 1610

```
 $array.'Profit' | measure-object -property length -minimum -maximum -sum -average
```

Returns a list of numbers...

- Count    : 5
- Average  : 5.4
- Sum      : 27
- Maximum  : 8
- Minimum  : 4
- Property : Length

Which the Sum doesn't add up?

What am I missing here?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$array | measure-object -property 'Profit' -minimum -maximum -sum -average`?

Comment: You don't need the quotes btw.

Comment: Remove `-property length`

Comment: ```$array.’Profit’``` is doing Member Access Enumeration to return an array that contains all the ```Profit``` property values which, if they’ve come from a csv file would be *strings*. ```Measure-Object``` is adding the ```Length``` properties of all those strings, which if you do it by hand with your sample data gives 27 characters. You’ll need to convert your strings into numbers before you can total then properly… e.g. ```$array.Profit | % { [decimal] $_ } | measure-object -sum```

Comment: Actually, Powershell will implicitly convert the strings to numbers for you, but the idea is still the same for what’s going wrong in your original code sample and it’s too late to edit my comment :-).

Comment: @mclayton The sum property will always be a double type, even with integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take your example right, `Profit` being a single property in each array element, taking off the reference to length (`-property length`):

```
$array = 1.1, 2.1, 3.1 | % { [pscustomobject]@{profit = $_} }

$array.profit | measure -minimum -maximum -sum -average

Count    : 3
Average  : 2.1
Sum      : 6.3
Maximum  : 3.1
Minimum  : 1.1
Property :
```

Or

```
$array | measure -property profit -minimum -maximum -sum -average

Count    : 3
Average  : 2.1
Sum      : 6.3
Maximum  : 3.1
Minimum  : 1.1
Property : profit
```

Minimum, maximum, sum, and average end up as instances of type `[double]`.

```
$array | measure -property profit -minimum -maximum -sum -average | % sum | 
  % gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Double                                   System.ValueType
```

Comment: To point to relevant GitHub issues: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12103 (your original issue about potentially lossy `[double]` output), and the follow-up proposal to allow larger integer types: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13423